# OOPS - installed Kylin and don't speak Chinese

Tags: system-installation, kylin

In my attempt to install a 32 bit version of Ubuntu I accidentally installed Ubuntu Kylin... is it possible to just remove the theme, or will I need to replace the OS with completely different version of Ubuntu?  If so, can someone direct me to a 32 bit version for my vintage Toshiba Satellite U305 S5077?

Comment: You can install English language support. I'm surprised you haven't chosen system language English in the installer - there's option for that. I'll put together an answer on how to switch system language, will let you know once posted.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Kylin is a totally chinese version. If you can find the keyboard settings you will be able to install more languages but ... good luck with that.

You can find all versions on the [releases page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) and the [alternative downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).